# Dealing with grammar mistakes with Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am looking for some assistance and tips on handling with building a Personal Assistant using speech input.

My project has several pipelines, one pipeline uses python's SpeechRecognizer and sends it to a new pipeline that parses the generated text in order to analyze what action was being asked and on what should it affect.

The problem is that some times I can get from the user the following kind of sentence:

*"Set volume to 86%"*

The problem with that is that when I use `en_core_web_sm` model I get that 'Set' is not a verb but adjective, but if I give it the sentence "Set *the* volume to 86%" then it is recognized as a verb.
This sort of weird behaviour messes up my assistant - do you have any tips how to handle with that?

Comment: In which way is this weird? 'Set' has multiple meanings tepending on its context and with the missing 'the' Spacy cannot guess what another more useful meaning might be. So this should be kind of expected behaviour you have to deal with in any NLP-task (expecially customers don't write Newspaper-like messages, which has to be taken into account when programming an assistant).

Comment: This sentence parses fine in spacy 2.3.x/en-core-web-sm/nd/lg: `['VBN', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'NN']` . Please edit the question to say what version were you using? and retest with latest

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to give a short answer to each of your questions, but keep in mind that some of these are still not really answered as a whole.

1. Spacy models are not 100%. I had several problems with POS tagging for Brazilian Portuguese and it seems you have a problem with english as well. Instead of handwriting patterns to be circumvented, I'd suggest you do POS tagging in some other source. A very good model is: [lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe](http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/services/udpipe/) - It is available for many languages and there are binaries for Python. Also, there's a REST API available
2. This involves SRL tagging. SRL stands for Semantic Role Labeling and are supposed to deal with things like "Agent", "Action", "Patient". It is a model based activity. Today, this is still an open problem. You can get some 70% accuracy in some cases, but this is usually domain bound and you probably would have to make some tweaks to the model yourself.
3. This is also a open problem. It's about question answering, which will hardly have a "plug into this software" solution. You can read more about it and the current solutions in the Association for Computer Linguists state of the art solutions: https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Question_Answering_(State_of_the_art)

Comment: My sentence are simple, tehrefore it is supposed to be simpler.
I think I might made the question not clear - the three point are part of my program, I can easily detedct the word "Set" as VERB if "the" follows it, but when there is no "the", it doesnt recognize it as a VERB

Comment: Yes, I understood. You have to keep in mind that this "tagging" process (which looks for each word in a phrase and decides whether it is a "verb", etc) is based on a machine learning model. This model is probabilistic and can vary according to the corpus (a tagged text dataset) used for training. The model used by spacy "guess" that the word "Set", according to the neighboring words, is a noun if there's no "the" closeby and verb otherwise. That's why there's this difference, got it? I told about another tool because its trained on a different corpus and so it "guesses" different.

Answer (score 2):

This sentence parses okay in **spacy 2.3.x** /en-core-web-sm/nd/lg: `['VBN', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'NN']`.

- At least the POS tagger correctly identifies 'set' as a verb VB* not a noun NN.
- Okay 'set' shouldn't be [tagged 'VBN' (verb past tense), it should be infinitive ('PART'?)](https://spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging)

Code (note we use suffix '_sm'/'md'/'lg' to denote model size):

```
import spacy

sy_sm = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sy_md = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
sy_lg = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_sm("Set volume to 86%")]
['VBN', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'NN']
>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_md("Set volume to 86%")]
['VBN', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'NN']
>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_lg("Set volume to 86%")]
['VBN', 'NN', 'IN', 'CD', 'NN']
```

And here's a harder stress-test for the model, note that sm,lg models differ from md; each is slightly wrong:

```
>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_sm("Set the set of sets to a set result.")]
['VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'NNS', 'IN', 'DT', 'VBN', 'NN', '.']
  ^^ - okay                                  ^^^ - I think this should be ADJ, it's not really a past participle
>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_md("Set the set of sets to a set result.")]
['VBN', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'NNS', 'IN', 'DT', 'JJ', 'NN', '.']
  ^^^ - not past tense                        ^^ correct
>>> [k.tag_ for k in sy_lg("Set the set of sets to a set result.")]
['VB', 'DT', 'NN', 'IN', 'NNS', 'IN', 'DT', 'NN', 'NN', '.']
  ^^ - okay                                  ^^ - should be ADJ
```